# Authorize to a rest api to consume it via rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authentication

I try to use a server (hibiscus) via a rest api from my rails code. The hibiscus api has, as far as I see, no login method or similar. When I make a call:

```
class Hibiscus < ActiveResource::Base  
  self.site = "https://10.0.0.128:8080/webadmin/rest/hibiscus/umsaetze/query/Telekom" 
end 

test = Hibiscus.find(1)
```

I only get:

```
ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess: Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.
```

Since hibiscus is a online banking app, there has to be some kind of login. In my browser I can open the according links, as soon as I logged into the system.

How can I make an authorization like the browser does in rails?

Or is there an even more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

If some one will have this again in the future: You only have to provide Basic Auth with you login credentials you have to enter, when you login to the browser.

In Postman it looks like this
[image: LoginAuth]